# Calculate surface area on raster using Python

Tags: python, raster, area

I have raster files (GeoTIFFs) and would like to calculate the surface area. I envision having a way to extract the coordinates at each corner of the pixels, then have the height values for each pixel and somehow combining those to calculate surface area. Any packages or methods that could potentially help?

Comment: In raster elevation defined in cell centers, not corners. Trivial task for any gis, that can handle rasters

Comment: Correct, cell centers hold the elevation(z) values. How do I access the centers from a file?

Comment: Load raster into numpy array.

Comment: @FelixIP How do I load the raster into a numpy array? I have never done that before.

Comment: https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/2016/Lesson7-read-raster-array.html

Comment: This is great, thanks! So how can I use this array to calculate the surface area of the raster?

Comment: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.7/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/how-slope-works.htm

Comment: I do not have access to ArcGIS pro. I am trying to figure out how to do this using Python. I can calculate the distances between the centers of the cells, but not sure how to get the entire surface area.

Comment: https://www.cuemath.com/geometry/pythagoras-theorem/ or install qgis . It will take 2 minutes to compute, because it can calculate slope from raster.

Comment: I see. And wouldnʻt running this in a numpy array go row by row or column by column, so some cells along side each other will get skipped?

Comment: @FelixIP Would running this method row by row accurately collect the surface area, or should this also be run column by column and add the row and column surface areas together to get the total? I hope that makes sense.

Comment: GIS computes slope using 8 cell neighbours, it also manages to do it on the edges. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/how-slope-works.htm

Comment: ooops. Not on the edges

Comment: @FelixIP Thanks! And what about computing surface area? I calculated row by row and column by column but it seems a bit larger than when using GIS. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: No,it doesn't make sense, because I don't know what you did.

Comment: I calculated the slope length (c) and went through each pixel/cell one by one in each row.

Comment: It can be a numbering of rows in numpy and gis, make sure it is the same as referenced